# Starting wpa_supplicant via script in systemd not working properly

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, fedora, wpa-supplicant

I've written a script to manually start the wpa_supplicant function on a Fedora/Centos7 machine with a wireless NIC. Due to static routing issues, I cannot use NetworkManager (nor do I want do with any type of work-arounds due to previous complications).

When I run `wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B dhclient wlan0` from the CLI everything runs just fine. I then run `dhclient wlan0` to get an IP and everything connects.

I've put the same exact command in a script, named "startuphelper.sh" in /usr/sbin/ - and then written a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts WLAN configurations (customized)
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/startuphelper.sh
TimeoutStartSec=15s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I've enabled this service (`systemctl enable wlanhelp.service`) - and it runs successfully, but does not actually start an wpa_supplicant instance (`pidof wpa_supplicant` yields nothing).

What am I missing?

EDIT1: reference the first comment, I did try using the pre-installed wpa_supplicant service, but that didn't seem to auto-connect on boot, either.

EDIT2: So I've obviously self-inflicted this problem, but when I enable the built-in wpa_supplicant service, it doesn't seem to like ssh logins from remote sessions. It just hangs and hangs on the "ssh root@1.1.1.1" on the client I'm trying to use to access the server. If I go into the machine from the console, and try to run much of anything, it just hangs.

SOLVED: Edit: So I didn't realize the built-in supplicant service needed the -i specified. Appears to be working now.

Comment: Why don't you configure and use the existing wpa_supplicant.service?

Comment: I was under the impression that required NM to be running and managing the if, is that incorrect? (either way, that didn't work either, so I guess the question still stands, but i'll update the OP to reflect).

Comment: Nope, it just runs wpa_supplicant with whatever options you provided. It's entirely independent of NetworkMangler.

Comment: I think I tried it earlier, but I'll try it again and post those results.

Comment: See above EDIT2 in OP.

Comment: Instead of answering the question in the question itself, please write an answer (and accept it). That will help anyone else with the same or a similar problem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a self-inflicted problem. Used the built-in wpa_supplicant service which didn't initially work, but I wasn't specifying the -i command in the actual service config file. I will update at a later time as to why my custom script did not work once I have more time to t-shoot.